# c++ - Convert an int array of 8 positions to char

Tags: c++, c++11, byte, bit

I have an int array of 8 positions representing 8 bits.

```
int zBits[8]={0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0};
```

zBits array is the character "z" in bits ("7a" in hex) (http://www.utf8-chartable.de/).

How can I convert this int array (zBits) in the "z" char using c++?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most straightforward way to do this is directly:

```
char z = (zBits[7]     ) |
         (zBits[6] << 1) |
         (zBits[5] << 2) |
         (zBits[4] << 3) |
         (zBits[3] << 4) |
         (zBits[2] << 5) |
         (zBits[1] << 6) |
         (zBits[0] << 7);
```

If you like, you can reformulate this into a loop which will be slightly shorter.